# How to make a 2 buttons that show/hide different layouts? (android, eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I'am trying to make a blank layout that contains 2 buttons, each views different layout and when one is pressed the other disappears, but I failed I can't even make one button to do that, so if you could help me fix my code that would be great.

P.S: I have only set one button.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/iB2"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/imageView2" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/iB1"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/imageView1" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#000000" />


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >
        ......

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

SoundPool sp;
int soundId;
LinearLayout Ll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.kh2fm2);

    sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundId = sp.load(kh2fm.this, R.raw.btnclick, 1);
    Ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Ll);
    ImageButton iB1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ImageButton iB2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    .....

    iB1.setOnClickListener(this);
    iB2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.iB2:
        sp.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        if(Ll.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
        {
            Ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
       iB2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
        .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a cursory glance would suggest that the L1 view is not visible to begin with, and once you click the button it is just reaffirming this. I assume the button click is working (sound plays, and the iB2 disappears), but L1/L2 aren't swapping.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" > <!-- This view is starting off GONE -->
```

The view is initially set to GONE in the XML. Then when you click iB2, you're affirming that if it were visible, that it will be set to GONE.

```
if(Ll.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) // It is already set to GONE in the XML
    {
        Ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
```

Additionally, the `findViewById()` is not retrieving the buttons, but ImageViews instead:

```
ImageButton iB1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); // Try R.id.iB1
ImageButton iB2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView2); // Try R.id.iB2
```